# How to add force in up direction at an angle in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am adding force in up direction of an object using
`ammo.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(ship.transform.up * magnitude);`
This way the ammo will always follow the direction of ship. How can i add similar force in up direction but with a slight angle, around 30 degrees?

Comment: Work out the length of the right angle triangle base when the angle at the top is 30 degrees and the height is 1. And put that in as your x or -x to get the 30 defree angle

Comment: Around which axis?

Comment: Well 2d wouldnt be z now would it.   Hence y up. X is side to side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the ships rotation and add your desired rotation to it like e.g.

```
ammo.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(ship.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler (-30, 0, 0) * Vector3.up * magnitude);
```

which takes the `up` direction and first rotates it according to the ships orientation and then from there adds another -30° on the local x-axis